# Invalid SQL Batch Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, mybatis, sql-loader

I'm currently creating an SQL*Loader statement for an oracle database but getting an invalid statement response. I have to create a loader that will upload from a text file, the path of which I have provided in the code. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in the statement. Its being run with mybatis.

```
<insert id="batchInsertCsv" parameterType="string">
        LOAD DATA
        INFILE #{filePath}
        INTO TABLE MC_MIDAS_BATCH
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            (
            VRM,
            MAKE_AND_MODEL,
            DATE_LAST_INSURED
            )
</insert>
```

The current error is:

```
-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: LOAD DATA             INFILE ?             INTO TABLE    
MC_MIDAS_BATCH             FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' #              
IGNORE 1 LINES                 (                 VRM,                  
MAKE_AND_MODEL,                 DATE_LAST_INSURED                 )
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL   
statement

at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:200)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:185)
at Upload.uploadBatch(Upload.java:46)
at UploadFileStreamService.batchInsert(UploadFileStreamService.java:203)
at UploadFileStreamService.chooseReadMethod(UploadFileStreamService.java:52)
at LambdaHandler.handleRequest(LambdaHandler.java:22)
at LambdaHandler.handleRequest(LambdaHandler.java:9)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$PojoHandlerAsStreamHandler.handleRequest(EventHandlerLoader.java:180)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:902)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:340)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:63)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:150)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL   
statement

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1052)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:610)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:253)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:86)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:928)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1136)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3640)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1384)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3752)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1079)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:74)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:50)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:198)
... 13 more

Caused by: Error : 900, Position : 0, Sql = LOAD DATA
        INFILE :1 
        INTO TABLE MC_MIDAS_BATCH
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            (
            VRM,
            MAKE_AND_MODEL,
            DATE_LAST_INSURED
            ), OriginalSql = LOAD DATA
        INFILE ?
        INTO TABLE MC_MIDAS_BATCH
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            (
            VRM,
            MAKE_AND_MODEL,
            DATE_LAST_INSURED
            ), Error Msg = ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
... 32 more
END RequestId: c6524410-4e35-494c-8616-7e77dffa8792
REPORT RequestId: c6524410-4e35-494c-8616-7e77dffa8792  Duration:   2831.48 ms  Billed Duration: 2832 ms    Memory Size: 2048 MB    Max Memory     Used: 289 MB Init Duration: 1724.54 ms
```

Comment: You are trying to run the content of a control file through JDBC - that won't work as the control file is not valid SQL command. The control file is an input for SQL\*Loader which is a command line _program_, not a SQL command. Through JDBC, you can only run SQL commands - if in doubt, the [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/index.html) will list the commands you can run through JDBC. If you really want to use `sqlldr` run it through `ProcessBuilder` with the appropriate command line parameters (e.g. passing the control file)

Comment: `LOAD` is not a valid SQL statement in Oracle. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SQL-Statements-DROP-TABLE-to-LOCK-TABLE.html#GUID-4DF57957-21B8-4033-A87B-1F37F27FD572

Answer (score 0):

First thing I find is that there are missing some **APPEND, TRUNCATE or REPLACE**, because probably you are inserting data into table with data.

I no understand if you are pointing to the correct directory to get the files, but I feel that the problem is that you need to TRUNCATE, or APPEND.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch05.htm#1004643